# Apache in jail wont start after portmaster upgrade

Tags: apache, freebsd, jail

HELP!!!!

I updated my web-server and now apache2.4 wont start after reboot.

After setting loglevel to debug, I get this in my logs when I restart apache:

```
[Wed Jan 21 10:24:21.785303 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 74642] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 21 10:24:21.785607 2015] [auth_digest:debug] [pid 74642] mod_auth_digest.c(250): AH01759: done
```

No http service is running, no pid file is created, ssl is not enabled.

Output from console when I restart apache:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache24 restart
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
Syntax OK
apache24 not running? (check /var/run/httpd.pid).
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
Syntax OK
Starting apache24.
```

Output from configtest:

```
apachectl configtest
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
Syntax OK
```

In conclussion: no errors, no useful log entries. How do I solve this problem?

Kind regards
Bernhard

Comment: It seems that apache doesn't load rc.conf because it doesn't read that apache24 is enabled.

Any clues, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it by hand, like this:

/usr/local/sbin/httpd -e debug -X

It will probably output a lot of messages; see if you can spot anything suspicious.  You can also try with "-e notice" instead, to reduce the amount of output.